# Remove duplicate Maps inside a List in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a nested List Example of data and I would like to remove the duplicated maps from the parent list

```
[
[ 
name: Zac,
age: 25,
car: mercedes,
],
[
name: Mike,
age: 15,
car: none,   
],
[
name: Zac,
age: 25,
car: mercedes,
],
[
name: Tiffany,
age: 28,
car: toyata,
 ],
]
```

Desired Outcome should be the following list with the duplicate removed

```
      [
      [name:Zac, age:25, car:mercedes],
      [name:Mike, age:15, car:none],
      [name:Tiffany, age:28, car:toyata],
      ];
```

Comment: In dart a List does not have key value pair, do you want a List of Maps, and if is a List what do they will contain?

Comment: ouw yes my bad an array of maps in Firestore basically

Answer (score 0):

Use toSet() for removing duplicates.
Suppose you store all list in List a=[.......]. Then for removing duplicates:

```
a.toSet().toList();
```

Comment: thanks for your comment but this removes the duplicates on the list level and not the nested maps underneath